# MySQL LOAD INFILE ... LINES TERMINATED BY “\n” triggers PAGER set to stdout in bash

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a simple csv file MySQL table in Ubuntu MySQL command line.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘/var/www/content.csv' 
INTO TABLE content 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ 
LINES TERMINATED BY “\n” 
(@id, @title) 
SET id = @id, title = @title;
```

I get *PAGER set to stdout* and I am not able to execute the SQL statement

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘/var/www/content.csv' INTO TABLE contentWithId
    '> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
    '> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
**PAGER set to stdout**
    '> (@id, @title)
    '> SET
    '> id = @id,
    '> title = @title;
```

Upon research, I have found that \n sets the pager. How do I import the csv file without modifying the csv file.

Comment: Are you really using these funky `’` quotes? You should be using regular single quotes instead.

Comment: Always turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?